# Creating a table/report using pandas using CSV/Excel/SPSS file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, spss

I need to create table or data tabulation for a CSV or Excel or SPSSfile which has 100 respondents with 56 variables in the data file with pandas or any other library using Python only, could you please help me out as I tried this but was not able to create a table of more than 2 variables.

I used pandas library for trying the above requirement.

I need to create excel file which has separate tables something like below `Gender`/`Age` in rows and other questions in columns.

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8 Column9 Column10    Column11    Column12
Question No.    Code            Total                       RQ2 
                Total   Male    Female  18-24   25-30   31-35   Yes No
Gender  Base                                        
    1       Male                                
    2       Female                              

Age Base                                        
    1       18 or below                             
    2       18-24 yrs                               
    3       25-30 yrs                               
    4       31-35 yrs                               
    5       36-40 yrs                               
    6       41 or above                             
    99      Refuse to answer                                
            Mean
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have written so far to attempt to solve this problem. Have you searched for pandas tutorials? This is a common use case.

Comment: Also, please limit your questions to "1 question per question". The SPSS file support seems to be [a separate issue #5768](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/5768).

Comment: Hi @i alarmed alien, could you please suggest for below

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below code for the above request.

> import pandas as pd df = pd.read_excel("Data.xlsx")
>
> ## print(df)
>
> Gender=pd.crosstab(df.Gender,[df.Gender,df.AgeDummy,df.RQ2])
>
> Age=pd.crosstab(df.AgeDummy,[df.Gender,df.AgeDummy,df.RQ2])
>
> print(Gender) print(Age)
>
> Gender.to_excel("DataTabulation.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1")
> Age.to_excel("DataTabulation.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1")

And below is the result that I am getting.

> Gender    1                       2            AgeDummy   3   4   5   6   7   8   3   4   5   6
> RQ2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2 AgeDummy                                       3  18  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
> 4 0   31  0   0   0   0   0   3   0   0 5 0   0   15  0   0   0   0   0   3   0 6 0   0   0   12  0   0   0   0   0   2
> 7 0   0   0   0   8   0   0   0   0   0 8 0   0   0   0   0   7   0   0   0   0

Which is not correct, I know "pd.crosstab" is not the correct syntax for me to use, but I am not able to figure out which syntax should I use for my requirement as I am not able to find out the correct answer on Google, as I need more than 1 variables in the columns and not the merged variables.

Also, how can I save both the variables(Gender and Age) created in the program in the same sheet after one below the other, as the above code saves only the last variable called and over-writes the previous variable.